# Why does paper.js path.onFrame not stop when changed from function to null

Tags: canvas, path, paperjs

I am trying to use path.onFrame to animate the writing of a path, where segments are added during each frame. I need to be able to stop the specific frame event for that path after it is finished, without removing the path. Here is what I have:

```
path.onFrame = function(event) {

    if(pathSegs.length > 0) {
        if(pathSegs[0].length > 0) {
            path.add(pathSegs[0].shift());
        }
        else {
            pathSegs.shift();
            path = new Path(pathAttrs);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('chalkboard finished - should only call once');
        path.onFrame = null;
        //writeText1();
    }
}
```

pathSegs is an array of arrays of path segments and this writes one segment to the canvas on each frame until the outer array is empty. When I set `path.onFrame = null` I'd expect to overwrite the original function, however my console log continues to print on each frame. If I were to set `path.onFrame = otherFunction()` instead of null both functions would execute on each frame.

Why is this? I know I could work around my issue but I want to understand what is happening that won't let this version work.

note: the end goal will be to trigger another animation at the end of this one, i.e. writeText1()

[paper sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are reassigning a new `Path` instance to the `path` variable, each time a new letter starts, without reseting its `onFrame` property.
So the `onFrame` callback is actually reseted only for the last letter.

What you should do instead of using the `Path` `onFrame` property which is misleading in your case, is using the `View` `onFrame` property which will work the same.

Here is the corrected [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).

```js
view.onFrame = function(event) {

    if(pathSegs.length > 0) {
        if(pathSegs[0].length > 0) {
            path.add(pathSegs[0].shift());
        }
        else {
            pathSegs.shift();
            path = new Path(pathAttrs);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log('chalkboard finished - should only call once');
        view.onFrame = null;
        //writeText1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense